# WPF c# progressbar only wants to update after a messagebox

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, invoke, dispatcher

As I have seen, many people struggle with the progressbar. I've been searching far and wide to understand an solve my problem. But somehow none of all solutions on stackoverflow worked for me. So I guess it's time to ask my first question to you guys.

In this sample code I have everything, that has to do with the progressbar given in WPF. The code works, exept from the progressbar updating it's value visually. If i call a MessageBox everytime the "progress" object changes, the MainWindow updates the progressbar and it is shown as it should.

Maybe I have coded something wrong? I do not get any exceptions or errors. Everything works fine and as intended except from the progressbar.

Below the code samples for viewing.

```
#region Progressbar

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the use of the Progressbar.
    /// </summary>
    private void startProgressbar()
    {
        progress = 0;
        gridProgressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ends the Progressbar by making it invisible for the user.
    /// </summary>
    private void stopProgressbar()
    {
        gridProgressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the progress in %.
    /// </summary>
    public double progress = 0.0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the current progress for the progressbar in %.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Number of finished data.</param>
    /// <param name="maximum">Maximum number of data.</param>
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    private void setProgress(int value, int maximum)
    {
        double v = value, m = maximum;
        if (m > 0.0 && m >= v)
            progress = v / m * 100.0;
        else
            progress = 0.0;

        txtProgressbarWorking.Content = "Working... " + v + "/" + m;

        //progressbar.Value = progress;
        //Thread.Sleep(100); // FOR await 

        //MessageBox.Show("" + (int)progress);
    }

    #region Backgroundworker

    /// <summary>
    /// Backgroundworker.
    /// </summary>
    BackgroundWorker worker;

    /// <summary>
    /// After the MainWindow has finished rendering, 
    /// the BackgroundWorker will be set up and be started.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Work-function of the BackgroundWorker.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("hi");
        for (;;)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (gridProgressbar.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                    {
                        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)progress);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception a)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
                }
            }));
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function updates the progress to the progressbar.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage), DispatcherPriority.Render);
        //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate () { }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
        //progressbar.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When User closes the whole program, we need to tell the
    /// BackgroundWorker to stop his work.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
```

The progressbar is "started" and "stopped" and the progress-value are manipulated like this. I have marked the code where progressbar-functions are called with some stars (**).
I had to call the "startProgressbar()" before the "openfiledialog.show" is called in "getExcelFileName()". After it the progressbar would not get visible. That's why it's called before the openfiledialog.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get's the whole data from an excel file into a DataTable object.
    /// The whole data is shown in a DataGrid.
    /// </summary>
    private void getArticleUpdateExcelData()
    {
        Excel.Application appExl;
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
        Excel.Range ShtRange;
        appExl = new Excel.Application();

        **startProgressbar();**

        //Opening Excel file
        string filename = getExcelFileName().Result;
        workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(filename);

        NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

        ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange; //gives the used cells in sheet

        //Reading Excel file.
        //Creating datatable to read the containt of the Sheet in File.
        table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < ShtRange.Columns.Count; ++i)
            table.Columns.Add("" + i);

        for (int row = 1; row <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            for (int column = 1; column <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; ++column)
                dr[column - 1] = (ShtRange.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString();
            table.Rows.Add(dr); // adding Row into DataTable

            //progressbar.Value = (row - 1) / (ShtRange.Columns.Count - 1) * 100.0;

            **setProgress(row - 1, ShtRange.Rows.Count - 1);**

            //progressbar.InvalidateArrange();
        }

        table.AcceptChanges();

        **stopProgressbar();**

        dataGrid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;

        workbook.Close(false);
        appExl.Quit();
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

I had a look at @taffer 's [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076924/c-sharp-winforms-how-can-i-display-a-loading-control-while-a-process-is-waitin/36079335#36079335) for a similar problem. I took the solution with the timer. Also i needed to execute all code lines, that had variables or objects from the MainWindow class in them with

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                workbook.Close(false);
                appExl.Quit();

                table.AcceptChanges();
                dataGrid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
                this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            }));
```

as example. This worked for perfectly for me and i managed to not have any performance issues. The progressbar updates very smoothly now.

Thanks to everyone who helped. Appreciate it!

Comment: Can you tell me whats your goal.  You want to show progressbar at the back of Messagebox?

Comment: The progressbar is in an own grid of the MainWindow class. With visibility changes it will be visible, if I read a file, and collapsed, if not.

Comment: Based on my understanding. On calling the `startProgressbar`, it shows the Progressbar on UI but after calling the `openfiledialog.show` which triggers the modal window that causes the progressbar to hide and not shown in the UI.  Is that what the actual problem?

Comment: nono, the progressbar and all is visible as intended. but if i call the startProgressbar after openfiledialog.show it doesn't get visible. but that's not the mainproblem here. (I'd just say, that this is a minor bug and can be ignored)
to say it very simple: I have e.g. a excelfile where i am reading 23 lines of data. The setProgressbar is sets the double value "progress". (how many lines of these 23 are already written into my DataTable. this value is between 0 and 100 (for obvious resons). I can see the progressbar, but it doesn't get green.

Comment: You mean the progressbar is not updating the status after the call of `openfiledialog.show`

Comment: the progressbar is not updating it's value while reading data from the excel file. i dont know what causes this. couldnt find anything in the debugger, internet, etc. the green bar just doesnt fill itself up to 100%. you only see an empty progressbar until reading of the file is finished. this is where the progressbar gets intentionally hidden again, because it isnt needed anymore (for now).

Comment: Where do you call this `getArticleUpdateExcelData` method from? It should be called from the `DoWork`; otherwise, it blocks the UI thread. Does my answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36079335/5114784

Comment: it's called by another function, which is called by a button click within the MainWindow

Comment: @taffer thanks for your answer .. sounds logical to me .. will give it a try.

Comment: Please post your solution as a proper answer. You can then even accept it.