# Preload a Form in Another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, winforms

I am trying to preload server form in the constructor of client form, in a separate thread. My reason is that server load is time consuming.

Here's the client form, you can see in the constructor that I am calling `Preload()`. There's also a button, clicking on it should show the server, which should be fast since the server form is already preloaded:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ServerUser server = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Preload();
    }

    public async void Preload()
    {
      await  Task.Run(() =>
            {
                server = new ServerUser();
                server.LoadDocument();
                server.ShowDialog();
            }
        );
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server.Show();
    }
}
```

Here I try to preload form `ServerUser` in constructor of `Form1` and if I click on button1 Server form show faster

And here's the server form:

```
public partial class ServerUser : Form
{
    public ServerUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void LoadDocument()
    {
        ConfigureSource();
    }

    public void ConfigureSource()
    {
        InvokeUpdateControls();
    }

    public void InvokeUpdateControls()
    {
          UpdateControls();
    }

    private void UpdateControls()
    {
        richTextBox1.Rtf = Resource1.ReferatPPC_Bun___Copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink your design. You should create all forms from the main UI thread, and offload the heavy lifting(non UI stuff) to the background threads. Calling UI methods from background threads results in undefined behavior or exceptions.

Also, I think you misunderstand what `await` does. You call `Preload()` synchronously even though it is an asynchronous method. This means that by the time `server.Show();` is called, Server might still be running one of these methods:

```
server = new ServerUser(); //you should move this outside of Task.Run()
server.LoadDocument(); //implement this method using background threads
server.ShowDialog(); //this will actually throw an exception if called via Task.Run();
```

From your sample I suppose LoadDocument is the expensive operation. You should rewrite that method to run on a background thread and make `ServerUser` show a loading screen untill `LoadDocument()` completes. Make sure that all UI methods from LoadDocument are called via [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) 
or **proper** async/await.

Comment: thank! I understand! But I don t want a splash screen!

Comment: Then disable the editable controls/buttons on the Server form until it has completed loading and show a small loading icon at the bottom of the form. This question might get you started on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076924/c-sharp-winforms-how-can-i-display-a-loading-control-while-a-process-is-waitin

Answer (score 0):

Send in constructor;

```
public partial class ServerUser : Form
{
public ServerUser(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form1.Preload();
}
public void LoadDocument()
{
    ConfigureSource();
}

public void ConfigureSource()
{
    InvokeUpdateControls();
}

public void InvokeUpdateControls()
{
      UpdateControls();
}

private void UpdateControls()
{
    richTextBox1.Rtf = Resource1.ReferatPPC_Bun___Copy;
}
}



public partial class Form1 : Form
{
ServerUser server = null;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Preload();
}

public async void Preload()
{
  await  Task.Run(() =>
        {
            server = new ServerUser();
            server.LoadDocument();
            server.ShowDialog();
        }
    );
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server=new ServerUser(this);// or whatever you want
    server.Show();
}
}
```

Comment: these classes are in separate projects. I can not make circular dependence.Basically Form1 depend on the Server and I cannot use Form1 in constructor of Server class! do you know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: i dont know what exactly answer but you can use maybe delegate or another things simililar with delegate.

Comment: You shouldn't call an async method from the constructor. You should override the onload method and call it from there.