# C# Windows Form - Opening Forms Using Main Thread and User Thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Open Form (From1) using user thread and then open Form (Form2) using main thread.
But Form1 is always on top position
Out put come like this:
[image: this]

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace Load
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        Form loadingForm;
        Thread loadthread;
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadingProcessEx));
            loadthread.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Form F1 = new Form();
            F1.Text = "Form2";
            F1.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void LoadingProcessEx()
        {
            loadingForm = new Form();
            loadingForm.Text = "Form1";
            loadingForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show Form2 in top position (I believe understand my problem)
Thank You.

Comment: I'm told it's possible to run multiple WinForms forms on different threads, but I suspect it would take an insane amount of discipline to do it. You **really** don't want to to this. Also, you should learn how to format code properly (either with the `{}` button or with a three back-tick barrier above and below the code)

Comment: This really sounds like an XY-problem, since using multiple UI threads are i most cases a terrible idea. What is your *real* problem? Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: In report form, i want to showing first animated image windows form using user thread while processing main thread, then custom message box form show if any validation or any error occurs. so i want to show custom message box on top position.

Comment: @AshikInx: _"i want to showing first animated image windows form using user thread while processing main thread"_ - the main thread should not be used for any blocking operation because it makes the UI freeze. Instead, execute the _operation_ on a different thread and marshal back any UI updates (eg. to update the animation) to the main thread. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36076924/5114784) is possibly related question. For a custom animation the simplest solution is to use a `PictureBox` with an animated GIF so you don't need to update the frames manually.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it from your post and comment, you have a "report form" with these requirements:

- Stays on top of the `Home` form.
- Executes an animation.

---

To make it stay on top of the home form, use the `this` reference so that the home form is the `Owner` of the report form.

```
public partial class HomeForm : Form
{
    public HomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonReport.Click += onClickReport;
    }

    private void onClickReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var report = new ReportForm())
        {
            // Use `this` to make Home form the parent
            // so that child windows will be on top.
            report.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Animations**

To run animations on the report form, use async tasks for non-UI long running work, updating the UI thread in between the long running tasks.

[image: animation]

```
public partial class ReportForm : Form
{
    public ReportForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox.Visible = false;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
    protected async override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        if (Visible)
        {
            labelProgress.Text = "Retrieving employee records...";
            progressBar.Value = 5;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            labelProgress.Text = "Analyzing sales...";
            progressBar.Value = 25;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            labelProgress.Text = "Updating employee commissions...";
            progressBar.Value = 50;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            labelProgress.Text = "Initializing print job...";
            progressBar.Value = 75;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            labelProgress.Text = "Success!";
            progressBar.Value = 100;
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            viewReport();
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

**Report**

When the report is loaded, adjust the window parameters of the report form in its class.

```
private void viewReport()
{
    string imagePath = Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "Images",
        "template.png"
    );
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile( imagePath );
    Size = new Size(pictureBox.Image.Width + 10, pictureBox.Image.Height + 50);
    progressBar.Visible = false;
    pictureBox.Visible = true;
    FormBorderStyle= FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}
```

[image: report view]

*Image Credit:* [Venngage.com](https://venngage.com/templates/reports/employee-daily-activity-report-c453f126-bc4c-407d-abbc-165ed2b3f109)